# Conditionally creating a new vertex

Tags: c++, performance, coordinate-system

I have a function which gets called very often, for this test 30,720,000 times. It has to run in real-time, so performance is very important. Are there possible improvements?

```
// This function looks up in the vertice table wheter a vertice at that position already exists
// - If yes, return the vertice index
// - If no, create a new vertice and return the created vertice index
//
// @param cfg: Pointer to a chunkConfig struct
// @param x: x position of the vertice
// @param y: y position of the vertice
inline VERTICE_INDEX GetOrCreateVertice(float x, float y, ChunkGenerator::chunkConfig *cfg) 
{
    int x_pos = int((x*POSARR_ADJ_F) + 0.5f);
    int y_pos = int((y*POSARR_ADJ_F) + 0.5f);   

    int dict_index = x_pos + (y_pos * cfg->subdivisions_adj);

    VERTICE_INDEX dict_entry = cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_dict[dict_index];
    VERTICE_INDEX current_index = cfg->vertice_pool.current_vertice_index;

    if (dict_entry >= 0 && dict_entry < 65535 && current_index > 0)
        return dict_entry;

    LVecBase3f* offset      = cfg->base_position;
    LVecBase2f* dim         = cfg->dimensions;
    LVecBase2f* tex_offset  = cfg->texture_offset;
    LVecBase2f* tex_scale   = cfg->texture_scale;

    int pool_index = ((int)current_index) * 5;

    float base_scale = 1.0 / (cfg->subdivisions_f-1.0);
    float x_scaled = x * base_scale;
    float y_scaled = y * base_scale;

    cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_array[pool_index+0] = offset->get_x() + (x_scaled * dim->get_x());
    cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_array[pool_index+1] = offset->get_y() + (y_scaled * dim->get_y());
    cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_array[pool_index+2] = offset->get_z();
    cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_array[pool_index+3] = tex_offset->get_x() + (x_scaled * tex_scale->get_x());
    cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_array[pool_index+4] = tex_offset->get_y() + (y_scaled * tex_scale->get_y());

    cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_dict[dict_index] = current_index;
    cfg->vertice_pool.current_vertice_index++;
    return current_index;
}
```

`LVecBase3f` and `LVecBase2f` are vector-types provided by the graphics-engine I use. `VERTICE_INDEX` is a `unsigned short`, `POSARR_ADJ` and `POSARR_ADJ_F` is constant `2`.

This is the chunkConfig struct:

```
struct chunkConfig {
    int subdivisions;
    int subdivisions_adj;
    float subdivisions_f;
    LVecBase3f *base_position;
    LVecBase2f *dimensions;
    LVecBase2f *texture_offset;
    LVecBase2f *texture_scale;
    verticePool vertice_pool;
};


struct verticePool {
    VERTICE_INDEX current_vertice_index;
    VERTICE_INDEX current_primitive_index;
    VERTICE_INDEX * vertice_dict;
    float *vertice_array;
    VERTICE_INDEX *primitive_array;
};
```

Performance result measured by very-sleepy: [link](http://s22.postimg.org/wt24m9gzl/screenshot_130.png)

Version based on the suggestions made in the comments: [very-sleepy](http://s22.postimg.org/3lta19269/screenshot_135.png), [AMD CodeAnalyst](http://s22.postimg.org/jp5r123pd/screenshot_136.png), and the assembler for the slow-line: [generated assembler](http://s22.postimg.org/6z1inyvr5/screenshot_137.png),
I also made some arrays global, and renamed "vertice" to "vertex".

Comment: Why did you document parameters that don't exist?

Comment: What do those time figures mean? I seriously doubt the calculation of `dict_index` takes a whole second, assuming `subdivisions` and `POSARR_ADJ` are integers.

Comment: Oh, I missed to remove them :) I updated the question. The 1.00s for example means the three lines above took 1.00s, that's because very-sleepy samples the current execution pointer. The time-result always means the time of the lines up to the last time-result.

Comment: I have added more details :) Maybe that helps

Comment: A maintainability rather than performance note: It might help if you used real words in your design.  There is no such thing as a "vertice".  The singular of "vertices" is "vertex".

Comment: You're absolutely right, I always thought it would be "vertice" .. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get the logic behind the code but `x * base_scale` and `y * base_scale` are used multiple times - might help to compute them only once. If `POSARR_ADJ` is constant, get rid of `cfg->subdivisions * POSARR_ADJ` too.

Comment: @bkdc I removed `x*base_scale` but I don't think I can remove `cfg->subdivisions * POSARR_ADJ` because I cast y to an int (`y_pos`) before.

Comment: @TobSpr `y` has nothing to do with `cfg->subdivisions * POSARR_ADJ` and you can leave `y` untouched. I don't know what `cfg` is but if you can change it, then it is pretty easy to define a `void set_subdivisions(whaever)` that will not only set the value for `subdivisions` but also precompute the value for `cfg->subdivisions_adj = cfg->subdivisions * POSARR_ADJ` - you can then use '`cfg->subdivisions_adj` in your function.

Comment: I have edited it, and also attached the cfg struct :) Is that what you mean?

Comment: @TobSpr yes. also...what's the point of `&& dict_entry < 65535`? While it won't help, performance wise, I'd go for `if (current_index > 0 && dict_entry >= 0)` - no point in doing anything if the pool is empty; `current_index` sounds a bit misleading too since it's more like a total/size/length but that's debatable.

Comment: I check that because a `65535` in the array means it is an invalid/uninitialized value. (I'm using memset to fill the array initial with `0xFFFF`). `current_index` is the current index in the array to write the next vertex to.

Comment: I also uploaded a new result based on the suggestions you made.

Comment: @TobSpr those timings are all over the place - time for a new profiler maybe? What compiler are you using? On what platform?

Comment: I'm using VS2008 on Windows 7. Are there profilers you could recommend? I was also able to increase the speed by 30% by enabling SSE2 (because of the int-casts).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10353/discussion-between-tobspr-and-bkdc)

Comment: Reupload images on some other hosting.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your function is actually doing 2 things:

1. It's checking to see if an entry exists in the dictionary, and if so return it
2. If it doesn't exist, then it creates a new one

So I would break it into 2 functions:

```
VERTICE_INDEX FindVerticeInDict(const float x, const float y, 
    const ChunkGenerator::chunkConfig& cfg, VERTICE_INDEX& current_index);
VERTICE_INDEX GetOrCreateVertice(const float x, const float y,
    ChunkGenerator::chunkConfig *cfg);
```

Note that I made `x` and `y` constants because they aren't changed by either function. Also, in the `Find` method, I made the `cfg` argument `const` because it's not being changed there either. It is modified in `GetOrCreate` though, so I left it as a pointer. (It could also be a non-const reference, if you prefer that style.)

I would create a named constant for the "entry not found" value:

```
const VERTICE_INDEX ENTRY_NOT_FOUND = 0xFFFF;
```

So it would look something like this:

```
VERTICE_INDEX FindVerticeInDict(const float x, const float y, 
    const ChunkGenerator::chunkConfig& cfg, VERTICE_INDEX& current_index) 
{
    int x_pos = int((x*POSARR_ADJ_F) + 0.5f);
    int y_pos = int((y*POSARR_ADJ_F) + 0.5f);   

    int dict_index = x_pos + (y_pos * cfg.subdivisions_adj);

    VERTICE_INDEX dict_entry = cfg.vertice_pool.vertice_dict[dict_index];
    current_index = cfg.vertice_pool.current_vertice_index;

    if (dict_entry >= 0 && dict_entry < ENTRY_NOT_FOUND && current_index > 0)
        return dict_entry;

    return ENTRY_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

For your vertex array, you really should create a struct that contains the members you're going to use rather than looking them up in a 1D array of `float`s. It's error prone, hard-to-read, and hard-to-maintain the way you're doing it now. I'd create a struct like this:

```
typedef struct Vertex {
    Point3D vertex_coord; // This might be the same as LVecBase3f?
    Point2D texture_coord; // This might be the same as LVecBase2f?
} Vertex;
```

Where `Point3D` is just:

```
typedef struct Point3D {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Point3D;
```

and `Point2D` just has an `x` and `y` float values. Doing this will allow you to remove the magical `pool_index = ((int)current_index) * 5;`, and have names for the values you're writing.

Also, you don't need to use the `inline` directive. The compiler can decide to ignore it, and it can decide to make something you didn't mark as inline inline. So there's not a lot of reason to use it.

You can reduce the verbosity of your code, and possibly reduce the number of pointer dereferences the compiler produces by getting the address of the vertex you want and assigning all its members through that one pointer.

Given the above, your function would now look like this:

```
VERTICE_INDEX GetOrCreateVertice(const float x, const float y, 
    ChunkGenerator::chunkConfig *cfg) 
{
    VERTICE_INDEX current_index = 0;
    VERTICE_INDEX dict_entry = FindVerticeInDict(x, y, *cfg, current_index);
    if (dict_entry != ENTRY_NOT_FOUND)
        return dict_entry;

    LVecBase3f* offset      = cfg->base_position;
    LVecBase2f* dim         = cfg->dimensions;
    LVecBase2f* tex_offset  = cfg->texture_offset;
    LVecBase2f* tex_scale   = cfg->texture_scale;

    float base_scale = 1.0 / (cfg->subdivisions_f-1.0);
    float x_scaled = x * base_scale;
    float y_scaled = y * base_scale;

    Vertex* vertex = &cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_arry [ current_index ];
    vertex->vertex_coord.x = offset->get_x() + (x_scaled * dim->get_x());
    vertex->vertex_coord.y = offset->get_y() + (y_scaled * dim->get_y());
    vertex->vertex_coord.z = offset->get_z();
    vertex->texture_coord.x = tex_offset->get_x() + (x_scaled * tex_scale->get_x());
    vertex->texture_coord.y = tex_offset->get_y() + (y_scaled * tex_scale->get_y());

    cfg->vertice_pool.vertice_dict[dict_index] = current_index;
    cfg->vertice_pool.current_vertice_index++;

    return current_index;
}
```